# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'set') Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm making a Discord bot, but there was an error and i can't find a solution!
I hope someone can find it. This is the Code:

EventHandler

```
async function loadEvents(client) {
  const { loadFiles } = require("../Functions/fileLoader");
  const ascii = require("ascii-table");
  const table = new ascii().setHeading("Event", "Status");

  await client.events.clear();

  const Files = await loadFiles("Events");

  Files.forEach((file) => {
    const event = require(file);

    const execute = (...args) => event.execute(...args, client);
    client.event.set(event.name, execute);

    if (event.rest) {
      if (event.once) client.rest.once(event.name, execute);
      else client.rest.on(event.name, execute);
    } else {
      if (event.once) client.once(event.name, execute);
      else client.on(event.name, execute);
    }

    table.addRow(event.name, "");
  });

  return console.log(table.toString(), "\nLoaded Events.");
}

module.exports = { loadEvents };
```

fileLoader

```
const { glob } = require("glob");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const proGlob = promisify(glob);

async function loadFiles(dirName) {
  const Files = await proGlob(
    `${process.cwd().replace(/\\/g, "/")}/${dirName}/**/*.js`
  );
  Files.forEach((file) => delete require.cache[require.resolve(file)]);
  return Files;
}

module.exports = { loadFiles };
```

Can anyone find the error?

[This is the Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gTLrq.png)

Comment: It means `client.event` is `undefined`. What do you expect it to be?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search in the docs revealed, `client.event` is not a valid property, and so you are trying to call the `set` function on something that is not defined (in your case `client.event`.

But what are you trying to achieve with this line?

```
client.event.set(event.name, execute);
```

[image]

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client

Answer (score 0):

Typo prob!
your constant is client.events: `await client.events.clear()`

but you set for client.event: `client.event.set(event.name, execute);`

you have to use either client.event or client.events and its must be declare in index.js
`client.event(s) = new Collection();`